# If the number of units of a ring is odd, then the ring has cardinality as a power of two

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

If the number of units of a finite ring is odd, then  does the ring has cardinality as a power of $2$?

I think yes. For fields, it is trivial. For non-fields, it is a hard question for me. I saw a paper [here](https://math.illinoisstate.edu/schebol/unit-cardinality.pdf) that sates that an odd number is the cardinality of the group of units of a ring if it is of the form $\prod_i (2^{n_i}-1)$. But, that proof is quite lengthy, and still the ring need not be a power of $2$. Any short proof? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Try proving the contrapositive.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan so, if a ring is not a power of $2$, then it still can have an odd number of units right? why should always have an even number of units? Should we assume commutativity of rings here?

Comment: No, commutativity is unnecessary. It is in fact true that if a finite ring has cardinality that's not a power of $2$ then it has an even number of units, and as a hint, the proof is short.

Comment: @Bernard well, here I assume the ring is finite. Edited the poat.

Comment: The early parts of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/492424/11619) also answer your question. Not sure whether call this a duplicate or not.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen yes, that is a really good and short answer, and includes some more than what I asked.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Consider the canonical ring morphism $\varphi \colon \mathbb{Z} \to R$. Since $\mathbb{Z}^{\times} = \{-1, 1\}$, the induced group morphism $\mathbb{Z}^{\times} \to R^{\times}$ must be trivial by Lagrange, so $\varphi(1) = \varphi(-1) = 1$. In particular, $\varphi$ factors through an injective morphism $\mathbb{F}_{2} \to R$, so $R$ is an $\mathbb{F}_{2}$-vector space, and thus must have cardinality a power of $2$.

Comment: why cant the induced map have two elements in the image?

Comment: @vidyarthi: by hypothesis, the order of $R^{\times}$ is odd, so it cannot contain a subgroup of order $2$ (namely, the injective image of $\mathbb{Z}^{\times}$).

Comment: The part " $\varphi$ factor through an injective morphism from $\mathbb{F}_2\to R$" is not sufficiently clear to me, though

Comment: @vidyarthi: if $R$ is the zero ring, then the original claim is evident. If $R$ is nonzero, then the kernel $\varphi$ contains $2$ and is not all of $\mathbb{Z}$, and so must be $2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: no, I got that the kernel is $\mathbb{Z}_2$. But how is it injective, it is certainly not injective right?

Comment: @vidyarthi: For any ring homomorphism $\alpha \colon S \to T$, the canonical induced map $S/\mathrm{ker}(\alpha) \to T$ is always injective. (But as a cheap aside: a (unital) ring morphism from a field to any ring is always injective.)

Comment: @AlexWertheim Well, from a field to any *nonzero* ring! :^)

Comment: @AlexWertheim sorry, but is not $\varphi(-1)=\varphi(1)$  here?

Comment: Stahl: haha, yes, careless of me! @vidyarthi: yes, $\varphi(-1) = \varphi(1)$. But $1$ and $-1$ are identified in the quotient $\mathbb{F}_{2} = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, so the *induced* map $\mathbb{F}_{2} \to R$ is injective.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is meant by "$\varphi$ factors through an injective morphism" and how that allows us to conclude $R$ is an $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space?

Comment: @AlexWertheim: sorry, I forgot to tag you in my previous comment!